# Triple Boot: Windows 7, Ubuntu, and Debian

Tags: grub2, debian

Is it possible to install Win 7, Ubuntu, Debian as triple boot? If so, which one should I install first after Win 7? Will there be problem with GRUB? and Is it fine to install those two linux in logical/extended partition?

Comment: Just install windows 1st, then any linux distribution

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is definitely possible (I've done it before).

Windows 7 first so it doesn't overwrite GRUB, and then Ubuntu or Debian can be installed in whatever order you please. They will both install their version of GRUB onto your master boot record, but Ubuntu's will likely be a more recent version.

It is fine to use logical partitions, although you might have to [chainload](http://www.brunolinux.com/05-Configuring_Your_System/Multiboot_grub.html) GRUB. As long as you aren't making any other partitions, you should be fine to install them all on primary partitions though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can have n number of operating systems and boot any one using grub (it must be detectable by grub)
2. It does not matter which comes first. There is no Hard and Fast rule to partition the HD.
3. It is fine to install two linux in extended partitions. 
   [I even have successfully installed Windows 7 on my last partition and Ubuntu on first, So I guess do not worry about the order]

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible

you should install the windows 7 ,debian and in the last ubuntu . grub2 automatically detect the other os

1 - make sure it will not go beyond the 4 primary parition if it so then your pc will not boot up

2 - you can make extra partion by gparted tool but it will not more than 4 in case of primary partition while other extented parition is allowed

3 - after having the sufficient space for third linux distro install it  grub2 automatically detect the other os .

4 - if any problem occur then reinstall grub2 of ubuntu

here is the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I

5 - now you are able to use all the three os installed in your pc

if the other distro is not show in grub2 menu then

you can updage ubuntu grub2 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJDcyAncmRY